# Previous screen is not clearing in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d, blit

Here I'm trying move which is blotted on the screen but the image moving without clearing the previous one

```
balloon=pygame.image.load("BALLON 1".png)
Bal_x=0
       
while true:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    Bal_x+=1
    screen.blit(BALLON,(Bal_x.120))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

[It moves like in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV09G.jpg)

Comment: Is the issue sovled?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the display with [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) in every frame:

```py
balloon=pygame.image.load("BALLON 1".png)
Bal_x=0
       
while true:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    Bal_x+=1

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) # <--- this is missing

    screen.blit(BALLON,(Bal_x.120))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)